# Read output and input each line separately - Python/SecureCRT

Tags: python, string, list, secure-crt

I am trying to get a Python script to read the output of a command, then to run multiple commands based on the list it receives. I don't generally write VBS or Python, so I'm getting stuck. (it's ugly)

```
def Main():
    objTab = crt.GetScriptTab()
    objTab.Screen.Synchronous = True
    objTab.Screen.IgnoreEscape = True
    objTab.Screen.Send("scsi i dev select 1" + chr(13))
    objTab.Screen.WaitForString("============")
    szPrompt = ">"
    szResult = objTab.Screen.ReadString(szPrompt)
    crt.Dialog.MessageBox(szResult)
    crt.Screen.Send("scsi i gen" + (szResult) + "w 0 100 1 0")

Main()
```

The input is working (albeit, I wish it would ignore the beginning of the > text (`sn200028` in this case). It's not important that it does though.

[image]

The next 2 parts I am stuck on, namely:

Part 1. How to get it to send the correct output. The correct output should be:

```
scsi i gen X w 0 100 1 0
```

where `X` is one of the numbers in this list.

Part 2. I need it to actually send this command for each item in the list. Not the whole list as `X`.

Any help is appreciated. Right now we have to copy and paste the lists, then awk them into another list, which is then cut and pasted. It would be much more beneficial to just run this from SecureCRT.

Comment: I don't know what is the problem you're solving, but possibly [Ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible) or [SaltStack](https://github.com/saltstack/salt) are more appropriate tools for it. If not that, consider using [paramiko](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko) directly instead of scripting a terminal emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
def Main():
    objTab = crt.GetScriptTab()
    objTab.Screen.Synchronous = True
    objTab.Screen.IgnoreEscape = True
    objTab.Screen.Send("scsi i dev select 1" + chr(13))
    objTab.Screen.WaitForString("============")
    objTab.Screen.Send(chr(13))
    szPrompt = "s"
    szResult = objTab.Screen.ReadString(szPrompt)
    result = crt.Dialog.MessageBox('Press OK to erase the first 100 blocks of the following devices: \n' + (szResult) , 'Run?' , ICON_QUESTION | BUTTON_YESNO | DEFBUTTON2)
    if result == IDNO:
        return
    if result == IDYES:
        vList = szResult.splitlines()
    for strString in vList:
        crt.Dialog.MessageBox('scsi i gen' + (strString) + ' w 0 100 1 0' + chr(13))

Main()
```

I was able to use str.splitlines in order to split each line then add it to the messagebox.